# How to add a float number into a list until the lenght of the list equals N number?

Tags: python-3.x, list, addition, items

I have to create a program where it asks for the length of a list of float numbers, then it should ask for the float numbers in the list and finally it will print the average of those numbers. Working with Python 3.

I have tried with `list.extend` and adding the number with an assignment into the list and adding a float input.

```
numbersInTheList=int(input())
thoseNumbers=[]
while len(thoseNumbers)!=numbersInTheList:
    thoseNumbers=thoseNumbers + float(input())    
print(sum(thoseNumbers)/numbersInTheList)
```

I expect the output to be the average of the numbers in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.extend` is used to extend one list with another. In this case, you want to `append` a single value to an existing list.

```
numbersInTheList= int(input())
thoseNumbers = []
while len(thoseNumbers) != numbersInTheList:
    thoseNumbers.append(float(input()))
print(sum(thoseNumbers)/numbersInTheList)
```